# Vlookup not working when result is N/A

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I want to know the Date from each value in column A. For this I am using a `VLookup` function on VBA, but when a value is not found (=N/A) the code stops.

How should I handle this error?

Here´s the code:

```
Sub lapse_Function()

Dim wsAll As Worksheet
Dim wsDb As Worksheet

Dim lapse As Variant
Dim startDate As Date
Dim Lookup_Range As Range
Dim ID_number As Object

Set wsDb = Worksheets("Database")
Set wsAll = Worksheets("All data")

'Run function
rowNo = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 2))
    'Set values
    studyDate = DateValue("March 3, 2017")

    Set Lookup_Range = wsAll.Range(wsAll.Cells(1, 1), wsAll.Cells(500, 3))
    Set ID_number = wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 2)

    lapse = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ID_number, Lookup_Range, 3, False) 'Here is where the code stops. I have next the IF in case of error but it won't work
    'Assing value
    If IsError(lapse) Then
        Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = "Less than 4 months" 'NOT WORKING
    Else
        If ((studyDate - lapse) / 7) < 52 Then
            Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = Round(((studyDate - lapse) / 7), 0) & " weeks"
        Else
            Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = Round(((studyDate - lapse) / 360), 1) & " months"
        End If
    End If
    rowNo = rowNo + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the code stops"?  If you are getting an error message, what is that message? `IsError()` can test for error *values* that `VLOOKKUP` returns, but it won't catch VBA runtime errors. It isn't designed for that.

Comment: Use: Application.VLookup. Instead of: Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup

Comment: You will have to use `On Error Resume Next` to continue execution when an error is encountered. To undo it, `On Error GoTo 0` Then to test for error, `If Err.Number <> 0 Then : ' Reset Error : Err.Clear`. You may also want to `Dim lapse As Date : lapse = CDate(...VLookUp...)`

Answer (score 0):

**1)** - In order to trap the error of `VLookup` after with `If IsError(lapse) Then`, you need to use `Application.VLookup`  instead of the `WorksheetFunction` (as stated by @user3598756 ).

**2)** - later your `Cells` are not fully qualified with the `Worksheets` , the line:
`Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = "Less than 4 months"`

should be :

```
wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = "Less than 4 months"
```

**3)** Instead of using

```
If ((studyDate - lapse) / 7) < 52 Then
```

You can use the `DateDiff` function, with the first parameter is `"w"` - stating the interval as weeks.

- The first place, it will be:

  `If DateDiff("w", lapse, studyDate) < 52 Then`
- The second place you can use

  `wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = DateDiff("m", lapse, studyDate) & " months"`

**Updated Code**

```
'Run function
rowNo = 2
Do Until IsEmpty(wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 2))
    ' Set values
    studyDate = DateValue("March 3, 2017")
    Set Lookup_Range = wsAll.Range(wsAll.Cells(1, 1), wsAll.Cells(500, 3))
    Set ID_number = wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 2)

    lapse = Application.VLookup(ID_number, Lookup_Range, 3, False)
    ' Assign value
    If IsError(lapse) Then
        wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = "Less than 4 months"
    Else
        If DateDiff("w", lapse, studyDate) < 52 Then
            wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = DateDiff("w", lapse, studyDate) & " weeks"
        Else
            wsDb.Cells(rowNo, 23).Value = DateDiff("m", lapse, studyDate) & " months"
        End If
    End If
    rowNo = rowNo + 1
Loop
```